# grpc c++ called CompletionQueue shutdown but CompletionQueue.next blocked forever when there is pending event

Tags: c++, grpc

There are two threads, one calls shutdown on a CompletionQueue

```
    debug_log("cq shutdown start\n");
    cq.Shutdown();
    debug_log("cq shutdown success\n");
```

And in another theads, cq.next blocked forever.

I can see there is one pending event in cq, 
but from documentation I expect that once I call shutdown, cq.next will start return false.

I don't know what goes wrong here.

Here is the call stack for cq.next

```
grpc_iocp_work(grpc_exec_ctx * exec_ctx, gpr_timespec deadline) Line 83 C
grpc_pollset_work(grpc_exec_ctx * exec_ctx, grpc_pollset * pollset, grpc_pollset_worker * * worker_hdl, gpr_timespec now, gpr_timespec deadline) Line 143   C
cq_next(grpc_completion_queue * cc, gpr_timespec deadline, void * reserved) Line 844    C
grpc_completion_queue_next(grpc_completion_queue * cc, gpr_timespec deadline, void * reserved) Line 873 C
grpc::CompletionQueue::AsyncNextInternal(void * * tag, bool * ok, gpr_timespec deadline) Line 71    C++
grpc::CompletionQueue::Next(void * * tag, bool * ok) Line 151   C++
```

Answer (score 0):

The API means cq.Next will return false once you have drained the cq. I am not sure what you meant by having one pending event, but if it is not the shutdown event, your cq.Next will still wait for that event to return before returning false (in the next call).